# What to do with questions with unsatisfactory answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

If I ask a question and I do not get any satisfactory answer on it, should I keep it open? The acceptance rate decreases because of these kind of questions.
Eg: [Quetion with no satisfactory answer.](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4673/how-to-grade-a-trek)

Should I go ahead and delete the question? Should we as a community close the question?

Note: The question in itself might be well framed and well suited for the site as such.

Comment: Your question was very good one but maybe too broad. A perfect answer to your question would have to tackle the criteria ("what are the criteria to consider when grading a trek") and then try to determine what criteria/condition makes a trek an easy or hard one. Your question for me need to be separated in two or more questions.

Comment: @Amine Thanks for the update. I guess I'll updated the question and see if there are any good answers coming up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question has good quality and should theoretically be answerable in a satisfactory way I see no objects to keeping it open and not selecting any of the possible unsatisfactory answers as solution.

Though this can be very subjective of course, there may be a grey zone, best may be to comment as to why you do not think of given answers as excellent. This may help otheres in giving the answer you are looking for or updating the already giving answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, keep it open.

Don't worry about silly statistics like acceptance rate. They would have even less meaningful value if we start cheating them.

Answer (score 2):

The very nature of the lack of accepted answer is that it gives opportunity and in fact encourages new users to give an answer. The greater problem I think we see is people not accepting an answer when one is acceptable.

Comment: I second that! +1